# Spring MVC 3: CustomDateEditor working but there is a validation error (BindingResult)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a problem with a validation error displayed when i submit my form with an empty date like that in the resulting web page:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type 
java.util.Date for property dateFin; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: ""
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes
    @Lazy
    public class MyController extends AbstractMVPAction {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/secured/cp/saveProgram")
        public String enregistrerProgramme(@ModelAttribute Program program,
                 BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model){
            if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
                model.put("program", program);
                return "/secured/cp/showProgram"
            }else{
                // ... saves the programme
                model.put("program", null);
                return "/secured/cp/backToOtherPage"
            }
        }
        @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                    new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"), false));
        }
    }
```

When I debug my method, I can see my object is fine, the modif I did are well reported, the date is null, but the bindingResult.hasErrors() returns true and according to me it shouldn't.

I used to have some validation annotations in the Program object and a @Valid annotation but I removed them all and still have the problem.

I have read lot's of similar issues and every time the solution is the @InitBinder/CustomDateEditor.
So it is there and I guess it's working, the dates are displayed the way I want (this was not the case before I add it) and I can submit them provided it's not empty.

Thank's in advance, I'm starting to go crazy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've constructed a CustomDateEditor that explicitly disallows the empty string. Check the [Javadoc for the constructor you're using](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html#CustomDateEditor%28java.text.DateFormat,%20boolean%29), when the boolean argument is false, passing an empty string to that editor causes the IllegalArgumentException you're seeing.

Try this:

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"), false));
    }
```

Comment: Definitly I needed a night, I was thinking of something like this at breakfast... Copy/Paste is evil! Thanks for your answer!